# Rubber and \include: Missing aux file

Tags: include, rubber

I'm trying to build a multi-file document with [Rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber). In `thesis.tex`, I have:

```
\include{intro}
```

and I have a file `intro.tex`.

It builds fine with `pdflatex`, but with `rubber -d`, I am getting the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'intro.aux'
```

Curiously, this is *only* a problem if `thesis.aux` exists AND `intro.aux` does not exist. If I delete `thesis.aux`, the problem goes away. The problem also goes away if I `touch intro.aux` (even if it's an empty file). So perhaps I will just put `rm thesis.aux` into my Makefile.

But I am still curious if there is a way around this, or if it is a genuine bug in Rubber.

Comment: I tried a simple [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with the same structure and it worked for me (Fedora 15, TeX Live 2011, rubber 1.1). It would be nice if you could come up with a MWE that actually reproduces the error. `:)`

Comment: *Addendum:* It might be worth trying to clean all auxiliary files, with `rubber --clean root`. `:)`